# how to autoresize height of div when content has different height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the height of a div, in which is content with different height, automatically resize when the height of the content is small ( so decrease the height of the div). The problem is: all the content is IN THE DIV but most of it is out of the screenview. (These are entries form a guestbook).
Here is the situation:
[image]

If all the visible content on the screen has small height: the div should increase automatically like below:

[image]

NOTE: there are always 3 entries visible on the screen. All the other are "out of screen" and waiting to slide in

```
<section class="section bg-image">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="nex-title">Wat klanten zeggen over ons...</h1>
        <h4 class="nex-undertitle">Ervaringen van klanten</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="nex-testimonials-slider">
        <?php include('guestbook/guestbook-slider.php'); ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

Css:

```
.bg-image {
background: #009de1;
background-size: cover;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
min-height: 500px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on if you mean: Your content (Guest entry) is loaded into the .container div or the .section div

**Loaded into .container:**
I seems that you have a `min-height` or `height` set on class `container`.

If you are referencing other libraries such as Bootstrap, you may need to override the `height` property of `container` with an `!important`.

Having no height set on this container, the container will auto size to the appropriate height for it's content.

```
.container {
    height: auto;
}
```

**Loaded into .section:**

If you are loading your content into `.section`, I would either:

A. move the pagination controls out of the `.section`, while still applying the rules for height from above.

B. load the guest entries into the `.container` div while still following the above height.